# crystal report c# tables and sections

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to make a report similar to what's in the [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyZBm.png)

Basically, there will be around 10 courses, each course has a chapter and the students evaluation for each chapter will be listed in tables as shown in the image.
I was able to add the first table using crystal reports, but right now I'm facing a problem with the second table the one about the recommendations/notes for each section, I'm unable to display it properly,I made a sub-report for it and what's happening is that the table gets displayed right after the first section thus destroying the  first table. What approach should I use to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest a subreport per table as I'm assuming your using the details section as the rows?

Comment: yes, I'm using the details section as rows for the first table and I created a sub-report for the second table and added it in a new section

Comment: @Alxwest should I make a sub-report for both the first table and the second one?

Comment: Treat all tables as separate subreports and put them in separate group headers so they only display once per chapter.

Comment: Thanks @Alxwest I will do it now and let you know if it  gets resolved, thank you for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: @Alxwest Can you share a like about how to group them? I'm new to crystal reports so I don't know how the grouping works there

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tB7o_H1eE-I